# org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader on second api call

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-excel

getting the error in the title when trying to invoke a springbatchjob secondtime with the same xlsx file.

Technologies used : Springbatch,springboot,mysql,java,springbatchexcel.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your configuration, my expectation is that your `ItemReader` is not step scoped.  Because of this, you use the same instance across multiple executions which can cause that error.  I'd bet if you changed that reader to step scoped, the issue will go away.

Comment: if i change it to stepscoped or jobscoped nothing happens(data not getting inserted into db for the first time also).

Comment: configuration here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231422/springbatch-step-is-not-getting-called?noredirect=1#comment87488713_50231422